# MongoDB $not vs $or performance

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've got a field called `locked_at` which can be null for not locked or a date. I want to select all documents where the lock is older than 10 minutes or not locked at all. There would be two approaches to realize this and I wonder which one I should chose.

**I will start with the $or approach as it is easier to understand:**

```
const minLockTimeMinutes = moment().utc().subtract(10, 'minutes').toDate()
const filter = { $or: [{ locked_at: { $lt: minLockTimeMinutes } }, { locked_at: null }] }
PlayerProfile.findOneAndUpdate(filter, updateDoc, options)
```

**Alternative with $not:**

```
const minLockTimeMinutes = moment().utc().subtract(10, 'minutes').toDate()
const filter = { locked_at: { $not { $gt: minLockTimeMinutes } } }
PlayerProfile.findOneAndUpdate(filter, updateDoc, options)
```

**Question:**

Is there a significant difference in terms of performance between these two approaches? Personally I think the $or statement is easier to understand as the lower one is some kind of double negation. ($not + $gt instead of $lt)

Comment: Did you read the manual page for [`$not`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/)? Becuase it actually includes the statement *"`{ $not: { $gt: 1.99 } }` is different from the `$lte` operator. `{ $lte: 1.99 }` returns **only** the documents where price field exists and its value is less than or equal to 1.99."*

Comment: Yes I read it but it's not relevant for my question I think? I want the $not behaviour and not the $lte behaviour. I am comparing $not vs $or. Am I missing something??

Comment: You are asking for a comparison on things that do things differently and are not the same.`$not $gt` is not the same as `$lt`. Read it again and try to understand why they are different.

Comment: Yes it is not the same, but I am not comparing $not $gt with $lt, chekc the second condition of the $or which should make sure that it's the same in the end?

Comment: I'm not blind, but apparently you need to be more observant. *"...field exists....."* means that the property need not be present. Again the whole premise of your question is comparing "apples" to "doughnuts".

Comment: Yes and since I am applying the $not it will also return only those documents where the field DOES NOT EXIST or where the value is less than equal minLockTimeMinutes? I still don't get it, sorry. The executed queries on my database seem to return exactly what I've expected.